# no such file or directory found in php

Tags: php

i have been trying to include the files using the  code:

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path='./../../';
$iai_root_path = "./";
include($phpbb_root_path.'extension.inc');
include($phpbb_root_path.'common.'.$phpEx);
include($iai_root_path.'includes/constants.'.$phpEx);
include($iai_root_path.'includes/load_functions.'.$phpEx);
```

I am getting the following error and i have been scratching my head for quite a while now ,don't know here am i going wrong

```
Warning: include(./../../extension.inc) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\alice\mods\iai\install.php on line 33

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening './../../extension.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\alice\mods\iai\install.php on line 33

Notice: Undefined variable: phpEx in C:\xampp\htdocs\alice\mods\iai\install.php on line 34
```

Comment: I think the warnings are quite clear. Try to remove both "./", there is no need in it.

Comment: Well? Don't leave us hanging. What's at `C:\xampp\htdocs\alice\mods\iai\../../extension.inc`? (assuming you haven't `chdir`'d before this?) Also, choose whether you're working on Windows or UNIX, those separators look drunk. :P

Answer (score 0):

Does your phpbb install live here "C:\xampp\htdocs\alice\" ?

Should you infact set `$phpbb_root_path='../../../';`

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this problem by writing my include statement by including a $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "includes/functions.php";
```

As for why this works, im not so sure.